# How to include a model which is not in default path

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have build a model by myself, it's a folder named "My_Model", it has correct .config and .sdf file. I can include it by moving the folder to default GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH, and write
"

model://My_Model

"
in the .world file. It works.

But what if I don't move this folder to the default path, and I don't want to modify the default GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH, how can I include it?
For example, its absolute path is /home/idontwan/Documents/My_Model, how should I write the script?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24935/how-to-include-a-model-which-is-not-in-default-path/) by [Idontwan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25994/idontwan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Idontwan,

As Clement mentioned you only need to add to `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` the path of your model. There is no risk if you modify this variable. When you open a new terminal this variable is reseted. If you want to make this change permanent edit your `~/.bashrc`.

You can check the current value of `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` typing:

```
echo $GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH
/usr/share/gazebo-9/models
```

then you can add your model path with, you can add as much as paths as you want, you need to split them using `:`

```
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:<path to your model>
```

Regards

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26408/ahcorde/) with karma: 281 on 2020-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1